# Rake tests use a different database than Hanami?

Tags: rake, hanami

I'm [getting started with Hanami](http://hanamirb.org/guides/getting-started/). (I use a different entity name, I started with reviews, not books, but otherwise I followed the instructions on the linked page.)

`bundle exec hanami db prepare` runs fine. The SQLite database is created. `bundle exec hanami db` runs fine

```
select * from reviews;
```

doesn't complain. `bundle exec hanami server` runs fine, I can load `'/reviews'`, I can create a new one with `'/reviews/new'`, then I can see the result again in the list. It definitely works with a database.

And then comes `bundle exec rake test`, which throws errors like

```
9) Error:
Add a review#test_0001_can create a new review:
Hanami::Model::Error: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: reviews
    /home/ytg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/hanami-model-1.2.0/lib/hanami/repository.rb:362:in `rescue in create'
    /home/ytg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/hanami-model-1.2.0/lib/hanami/repository.rb:359:in `create'
    ...
```

I suspect that rake is working from a different database file than hanami, because the table should really be there. But why? And how can I make sure that they use the same database?

EDIT: adding the Rakefile just in case

```
require 'rake'
require 'hanami/rake_tasks'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rubocop/rake_task'

RuboCop::RakeTask.new

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.pattern = 'spec/**/*_spec.rb'
  t.libs << 'spec'
  t.warning = false
end

task default: :test
task spec: :test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [create the db for the test environment](http://hanamirb.org/guides/1.1/models/database-configuration/#setup-your-database) before you run them:

```
HANAMI_ENV=test bundle exec hanami db prepare
```

Comment: so my misconception was, that even though I ran it on the same machine (which I thought to be completely a development environment), if it's about tests, it's a test environment. thanks

Comment: You should also apply migrations so I would write `HANAMI_ENV=test bundle exec hanami db migrate`.